# Could Chinese people being armed have prevented the Great Chinese Famine?

Tags: china, guns

Pro-gun people sometimes claim that more Chinese people being armed could have prevented the Great Chinese Famine. Can somebody explain to me how they think that?

I fail to see how that could be the case. The fact is that many Chinese people were armed and were killing sparrows under the Four Pests Campaign. It's precisely the armed Chinese people killing the sparrows that led to the Great Chinese Famine, by causing an overabundance of grasshoppers (which sparrows should have eaten) which led to massive crop failure. More Chinese people being armed would, if anything, cause there to be even fewer sparrows and made the famine worse. Am I missing something?

Comment: "sometimes claim"  please link to such a claim. Clearly there is a political aspect to this question, but it could also be considered whether [skeptics.se], [history.se] might not be better.  I don't think [farming.se] exists. It seems unlikely that the famine had a single cause and the sparrows were just one element.

Comment: To kill sparrows you would use birdshot in shotguns.  Not military, or even deer-hunting, grade rifles.  These 2 concepts are unrelated, making the premise extremely dubious.  China was also extremely poor at the time, so the idea that many peasants had even bird-hunting shotguns seems iffy as well.  Pre-1930s China was wracked by warlords.  Do you think they'd have armed the peasants?  Or tolerated armed peasants?  Yes, if millions of peasants had had AK-47s or even deer hunting rifles during the famine they might have done away with the CCP.  So what?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Millions of peasants had AK-47s during the famine. Who do you think the soldiers of Mao were? What pro-gun advocates fail to notice is that a heavily armed population can never save a country from tyrants... because those gun-nuts are pro-tyrants. I'm certain that 90+% of the guns in the USA are in the hands of Trump supporters. If anyone, anywhere in the world, tries to overthrow a democracy to institute a dictatorship they always have the support of at least 80% of the gun lovers of that country. Left or right wing, pro-gun correlates with authoritarianism.

Comment: @Rekesoft Indeed, spontaneous armed rebellion was the dream of Marx and Engels - e.g., in his introduction to Marx' [Civil War in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Civil_War_in_France) Engels waxes about how having the majority of the population armed naturally led to the overthrow of the liberal democracy and the establishment of the "people's government".

Comment: @Rekesoft, you may be confusing causation. One assumes that popular revolutionaries *seek out* weapons for themselves, rather than gun possession causing people to become revolutionaries. Whereas those who actually control the state hire policemen and soldiers to operate their weapons.

Comment: @Rekesoft First, lets get out of the way that I agree with your negative assessment of many US gun nuts.  Look no further than the culture at display on Jan 6th.  That said, think through what you wrote.  Soldiers are not peasants and typically aren't starving either, if a tyrant knows what's good for them.  Going by your logic, the soldiers in Mao's army would count AK-47 wielders, despite the absence of armed peasants.  By that logic, no tyranny can happen if there is an army with guns.  No one makes that claim that I know of.  No, the Q is:  armed *peasants*.  There likely weren't any.

Comment: That soldiers are drafted peasants doesn't change the fact that they are under direct government control, presumably well-surveilled, a limited capacity to self-assemble into hostile forces and subject to wide coercive powers under martial law (not that the Great Leap Forward lacked in coercive powers on everyone else).  Military rebellions are a dime a dozen historically, any tyrant watches for them carefully and they are probably not what 2nd amendment absolutists have in mind.  Rather they want to resist "armed Federal coercion" (I dont use "army" because many othe them love the military).

Comment: I always thought that they killed sparrows by banging pots and pans, keeping the birds flying from fear until they died from exhaustion. While simultaneously smashing all of the nests they could find...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Sure, I agree, for the context of this question. The armed peasants of Mao's army in th 1930's were the official Chinese Army by the 1950's. My argument was more in general about the pro-gun mythical romance of "an armed population is needed to stop tyranny", when it's always the part of the population which is armed who helps the tyrant - and usually became their official forces later. Whether it's Castro's mountain men or SS and SA members in Germany.